# How does one go about starting a Massive Open Online Course (MOOC)?

Tags: teaching, online-learning, mooc

Currently my university does not offer any MOOCs. I am interested in creating one. How should I go about it? Does my university need to sign an agreement with one of the providers such as Coursera or can I approach them independently?

Comment: For fun? I guess I don't know anyone who has actually taught a MOOC (my institution does not offer them either) but my impression is they're a fair amount of work and sponsorship from your university probably brings compensation of some form (monetary, administrative assistance, or otherwise).

Comment: MOOCS are platform independent and can be implemented on almost any LMS (learning management system)
A first step is to take a MOOC by yourself. It will give you a pretty good idea about the pros and cons.
Platforms providing MOOCS are constantly looking for new contents. New platforms emerge almost on a monthly basis.

Comment: Be warned: Building a good MOOC requires _at least_ as much work as writing a good textbook!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you don't need to have a signed deal with e.g, Coursera. You can do it independently. For example, the University of Helsinki has started offering some MOOCs, but they are not listed in the aforementioned provider.

One good approach would be to follow the line of Khan Academy, maybe it seems rather simplistic, but it can bring good results. One piece of general advice that I can give is to focus on quality instead of quantity. Just a couple of well-made online courses, with lecturers that have experience in the topics, is enough. Also pay attention to the evaluation tools that your site will have, that is crucial for its success and interaction with the prospective students.

Good luck in your idea!

Comment: Thank you Layla. Coursera does offer many tools though such as forums and more importantly a huge audience.

Comment: Just to add another data point, one of my alma maters just started offering independent MOOCs (though only for alumni, which I think is a super cool way to keep alumni engaged)