# Is it financially worth it to teach a MOOC (e.g. Coursera)?

Tags: mooc

I am not sure what the requirements are to teach a MOOC. I guess it is a little different, depending on which platform one is going to teach. As far as I undestand, Coursera offers only 15% of the revenue to the teaching team. Somewhere else it might be more, but the number of participants is smaller. Does someone have experience whether it is financially worth to teach a MOOC?

For this question please leave aside other benefits like getting known or the satisfaction of teaching. I see those as benefits, but that is not the question for now.

Also I am only counting money that flows from the MOOC platform to the team/organisation/company, not compensation from a university to the lecturer for doing the course (like discussed in [How are instructors compensated for teaching a Massive Open Online Course (MOOC)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11405/how-are-instructors-compensated-for-teaching-a-massive-open-online-course-mooc)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Coursera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coursera) works on a different model from [Udemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udemy). Basically, Udemy pays its instructors while Coursera does not. Coursera may split profits (or revenue) with the university, but as far as I can tell it does not pay the teaching team directly. Based on your constraints this means teaching for Coursera is not worth it. It is possible to make money teaching for Udemy. For example, in 2012 the top ten earners made 1.65 million [[1](https://gigaom.com/2012/05/17/a-new-way-to-make-six-figures-on-the-web-teaching/)] and a quarter made at least $10,000 [[2](https://gigaom.com/2012/11/30/on-online-learning-site-udemy-quarter-of-approved-instructors-earn-10k-or-more/)].

Comment: Is Udemy the financially most profitable MOOC platform, do you know?